# Opera Mini 8 on iOS 7 has strange page rendering with meta viewport tag

Tags: html, ios, mobile, opera, opera-mini

After update `Opera Mini` on `iOS` to 8+ version, there is a strange render bug in landscape orientation:

[image]

[image]

Example on screenshots([`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/vaciziru/1/edit)), html only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      Any big text here...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can reproduce it with [`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/vaciziru/1/edit) example:

1. Open in portrait orientation [`jsbin` example](http://jsbin.com/vaciziru/1/edit) in Opera Mini 8 on
   iOS 7 - the page width is 100% of screen width
2. Rotate to landscape orientation - the page width is more less than
   100% of screen width
3. Scroll to bottom - there is a free space after page

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`.

If I remove it in html([`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/vaciziru/1/)) - all looks fine. But user can scale now and on landscape orientation the page is zoomed.

HTML without this ugly behaviors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Any big text here...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Opera Mini developers answer to my letter. This is fixed in 8.0.2 version